# WinForms Blazor: Button click event does not fire

Tags: c#, winforms, blazor

I'm trying to use Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition to get a WinForms/Blazor Hybrid application working. I've followed [Microsoft's guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hybrid/tutorials/windows-forms?view=aspnetcore-7.0) to the letter and indeed: I get a Forms app that shows the Blazor "Counter" page as implemented in the guide.

However, the button's `@onclick` handler is not invoked. I can click as often as I want, the counter isn't increased and when I set a breakpoint, it doesn't stop there.

I added the web developer tools to the services using

```
services.AddBlazorWebDeveloperTools();
```

and placing breakpoints there I can see that on the JavaScript end, the event does fire in `blazor.webview.js`, but somehow it is not propagated.

The funny thing is: If I do the same thing on my work notebook using VS 2022 Enterprise, things work as expected. Exact same Microsoft Guide, exact same code...

Any ideas?